# Running script with locked cells

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I wrote the following script that runs correctly for me as the creator of the sheet with full editing rights. The sheet is also shared with another person with editing rights but certain cells are locked for that user. As a result when they open the sheet the script fails to run. The error seems to first appear on this line:

> var values = range.getValues().map(function(d){ return d[0] })

I have tried to rewrite the code but all I end up doing is breaking it. If I have to have the cells unlocked for the user then how can I ensure they cannot change the information entered there? The information is called via a formaula from a locked and hidden sheet.

```
function onOpen(){

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sheetsCount = ss.getNumSheets();
  var sheets = ss.getSheets();

  for (var i = 0; i < sheetsCount; i++){

  var sheet = sheets[i]; 

  var range = sheet.getRange(6, 3, 35);
  var values = range.getValues().map(function(d){ return d[0] }); 

  //clear previous border
  var selection = sheet.getRange(6,2,35,5)
  selection.setBorder(false,false,false,false,false,false);  

  //set border
  var index = values.indexOf("");

      var border = sheet.getRange(5, 2, index+1, 5);
  border.setBorder(true, true, true, true, true, true);}
}
```

Comment: Use "installable triggers"

Answer (score 0):

so if I have an installable trigger the script will run because the person has editing rights but via my credentials so bypassing the locked cells. Would the following adaptation achieve this?

```
function createSpreadsheetOpenTrigger() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  ScriptApp.newTrigger('borders')
      .forSpreadsheet(ss)
      .onOpen()
      .create();
}

function borders(){

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sheetsCount = ss.getNumSheets();
  var sheets = ss.getSheets();

  for (var i = 0; i < sheetsCount; i++){

  var sheet = sheets[i]; 

  var range = sheet.getRange(6, 3, 35);
  var values = range.getValues().map(function(d){ return d[0] }); 

  //clear previous border
  var selection = sheet.getRange(6,2,35,5)
  selection.setBorder(false,false,false,false,false,false);  

  //set border
  var index = values.indexOf("");

      var border = sheet.getRange(5, 2, index+1, 5);
  border.setBorder(true, true, true, true, true, true);}
}
```